# Добавление файла в удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Есть функционал динамического добавления файла в папку.
Хочу сделать, чтоб после того, как файл создался он автоматически добавлялся и в удаленный репозиторий github.
Погуглил, но не нашел прямого ответа.

Подскажите, что есть для этого (командная строка, API)?

Уточню, папка и файл ничего не знают о репозитории и не должны знать.

Comment: похоже на извращение, но возможно вот оно https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, сам вчера все таки наткнулся на это API, руки не дошли попробовать. Оформите ответом, а я после проверку плюсану если окажется верным.

Answer (score 0):

1. git add ... - добавить нужный файл в список на коммит. Можно добавлять по одному, можно по маске.
2. git commit -m "сообщение к коммиту" - закоммитить
3. git push - отправить коммит в удаленный репозиторий

Comment: Это я так понимаю, если папка под контролем версии?

Comment: @ezhov_da, вопрос в том, что как вы понимаете сам термин "папка под контролем версий"? Это все должно происходить внутри рабочей копии репозитория. сами подпапки рабочей копии добавлять под контроль версий не нужно, только файлы.

Answer (score 0):

У гитхаба есть апи. Там даже есть возможность произвольно залить файл - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

В одном с своих систем сборки используем подобное (правда для гитлаба), что бы записывать сообщения сборок.